# Open Chrome with specific user using Auto Hot Key (AHK)

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey, shortcut, profiles

Simply put to open chrome with a specific user you can use a shortcut like,

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Default"

with auto hotkey I'm not sure how to format this shortcut as such.

Does not work:

```
Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Default"
```

Does not Work

```
Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --profile-directory="Default""
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: The first code snippet is correct and works here. Maybe there's something wrong with Chrome on your end? Try killing all of its background chrome.exe processes in Task Manager - Processes tab.

Comment: It's not that chrome doesn't work its that I'm using AHK and AHK doesn't understand it when you right it like that becuase its not one string

Comment: Well, try using another version of AHK. Mine is 1.1.23.01

Comment: And the first one works for you? Even though it's a broken string?

Comment: 1. It's not broken, AHK just has peculiar syntax with literal text strings 2. It works here.

Comment: Your right I had a mistake in another place of my code, thanks for helping me realize that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work fine, I had a mistake in another part of my overall program caused an error.

```
Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Default"
```